# JQ событие наклона устройства deviceOrientation

Tags: javascript, ios

Мой код выполняет функцию по несколько раз за 1 наклон. Тем самым слайды перескакиваю не появившись. Как оборвать функцию и сделать так, что функция выполнялась 1 раз, за 1 наклон?

```
window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', function(event) {
    if (event.beta > '30' ) {
        prevSlide();
    } else if (event.beta < '-30' ) {
        nextSlide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перед запуском обработчика немного подождать и дать устройству стабилизировать свое положение

**Update** если телефон имеет чувствительный датчик, то событие `deviceorientation` будет срабатывать постоянно. Поэтому нам нужно его игнорировать если приращение угла поворота мало

```js
var timer = null;
// На первое срабатывание реагируем всегда
var oldAngle = 1000;
window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', function(event) {
  var angle = event.beta;
  var delta = Math.abs(angle - oldAngle);
  oldAngle = angle;
  if (delta < 2)  // Если уголо наклона изменился не сильно
    return;  // выходим
  if (timer)
    clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(function() {
    timer = null;
    if (angle > 30) {
      prevSlide();
    } else if (angle < -30) {
      nextSlide();
    }
  }, 500);
});
```

Comment: функция не срабатывает

Comment: @MaksymGloba В коде опечатка была. Вы его просто скопировали?

Comment: опечатку я исправил сразу, конечно же.

Comment: http://dev.onyx-lab.ru/mg-test-rot/mg-test-landing/mg-test-landing.html вот тут можешь по тестить на устройстве, я добавил алерты вместо функций смена слайда

Comment: @MaksymGloba Устройства нет. Отлаживать код нужно

Comment: на Android event.beta стабилизируется и функция включается, а на IOS event.beta постоянно в динамике и функция не срабатывает. Может есть идея как можно обойти эту проблему?

Comment: @MaksymGloba beta указывает абсолютный угол наклона? Или изменение от предыдущего?

Comment: абсолютное число

Comment: @MaksymGloba попробуйте новый код